# MVC equivalent of Webforms "UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

So I have this Controller:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Controllers
{
  [Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
  public class MyController : Controller

  public ActionResult Index()
  {
   ...
```

As you can see, only users with the Administrator role have access to MyController's Action methods.
So, from somewhere else *(another controller, another class in my library class, etc)* how do I check if *Current.User.Identity.Name* has access to MyController?
Something that works like *"UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal"* for WebForms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Webform's "UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal" equivalent for MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615870/what-is-webforms-urlauthorizationmodule-checkurlaccessforprincipal-equivalent) (Though it doesn't get in to authorizing action calls from other controller actions).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2197244/781792 for a potential solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to read the information from the other controller. This can be done by instantiating its context and the Descriptor, then instantiating the `AuthorizationContext` for that controller and read the filter info.

This is how you can do it

```
private bool ActionIsAccessibleToUser(string actionName, ControllerBase controllerBase)
{
    // Get controller context.
    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, controllerBase);

    // Get controller descriptor.
    var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerBase.GetType());

    // Get action descriptor.
    var actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(controllerContext, actionName);

    // Check on authorization.
    return ActionIsAuthorized(actionDescriptor, controllerContext);
}

private bool ActionIsAuthorized(ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, ControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    if (actionDescriptor == null)
    {
        // Action does not exist.
        return false;
    }

    // Get authorization context fo controller.
    AuthorizationContext authContext = new AuthorizationContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

    // run each auth filter until on fails
    // performance could be improved by some caching
    var filters = FilterProviders.Providers.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
    FilterInfo filterInfo = new FilterInfo(filters);

    foreach (IAuthorizationFilter authFilter in filterInfo.AuthorizationFilters)
    {
        // Attempt authorization.
        authFilter.OnAuthorization(authContext);

        // If result is non-null, user is not authorized.
        if (authContext.Result != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Assume user is authorized.
    return true;
}
```