# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API - How do I check if the action with given ActionDescriptor requires authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

Given an `ActionDescriptor`, for example the `ActionDescriptor` of the action located at `GET /api/Item/{id}`, how do I tell if it requires authentication or not?
Checking if filters of the method corresponding to the action, and possibly the filters of the class that declares the method are `AuthorizeAttribute` or `AllowAnonymousAttribute` is not reliable because in this way the policies of `AuthorizationOptions` (`FallbackPolicy`, `DefaultPolicy` and the policies added with `AddPolicy()`) would not be taken into consideration, for example.
I tried to check if the following interfaces had a method that accepts an `ActionDescriptor`, but unfortunately none of them have it:

- `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider`
- `IAuthorizationService`
- `IAuthorizationHandler`
- `IAuthorizationHandlerContextFactory`
- `IAuthorizationHandlerProvider`

EDIT: after searching a bit, I think what I need existed in WebForms: `UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal()`. I wonder if there is something similar for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @DavidG I need to check if the operation requires authorization to customize the Swagger UI

Comment: did you already tried something or you are simply assuming that it won't be sufficient ?

Comment: @CodingMytra as the question says, I can't rely on the presence/absence of `AuthorizeAttribute`/`AllowAnonymousAttribute`

Comment: that's what I want to understand the scenario, if you can write the code of the actual scenario where you don't rely of these attribute and achieve authorization . may be then we could help to achieve that.

Comment: I need to check that flag to add security (ex. Basic, OAuth) and apply 401 and 403 responses to the Swagger UI, to all the operations which require authorization

Comment: and how do you mark an operation that requires authorization without using these attributes?

Comment: @CodingMytra with `builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());`

Comment: that is just configuring policy but how do you specify to use this policy for a particular operation.

Comment: @CodingMytra it's not just configuring, it's configuring and enforcing. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0#require-authenticated-users)

Comment: ok got it. but in case of fallback policy enforcement, how do you decide which authentication mechanism is required. in my opinion you always needs a authentication scheme to be used for a operation if there are multiple authentication schemes are supported.

Comment: @CodingMytra I only need a boolean value which indicates if authorization is needed or not

Comment: ok. if you have fallback policy then you always need authorization. that's what I understand from the documentation you shared. so there is no question of "if".

Comment: @CodingMytra yes that's true for the specific case of having a `RequireAuthenticatedUser`, but we are going off topic from the question which asks, given an action (identified by an `ActionDescriptor`, raw route, `RouteTemplate`, etc), would the ASP.NET Core internal authentication handlers eveluate it as needing authentication or not?
Relying only on attributes or configured options cannot work because, for example, in the case someone exchanges the IAuthorizationPolicyProvider that loads policies and requirements from another source than the configured options

Comment: "would the ASP.NET Core internal authentication handlers eveluate it as needing authentication or not?" the ans is no. unless you specify authentication scheme it does not know which scheme to challenge. so it does not do any authentication unless you specify. i think you are mixing authentication and authorization.

Comment: I dig a bit and maybe you need to create your own version of as this SO question [MVC equivalent of Webforms "UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038186/mvc-equivalent-of-webforms-urlauthorizationmodule-checkurlaccessforprincipal/19038664). The code was based on ASP.NET MVC so please expect some porting effort to make it ASP.NET Core-ed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the filters with the authorization interfaces, so I think this should work:

```cs
if(ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.OfType<IAuthorizationFilter>().Any())
 //means the action has Authorization filter
        
if(ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.OfType<IAllowAnonymous>().Any())
 //means action has AllowAnonymous filter
```

Update:
Another way is to get all actions with their attributes

```cs
var projectAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Suxxeed.Analytixx.Api.Startup));
var controllerActionlist = projectAssembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
            .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any())
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Controller = x.DeclaringType?.Name,
                ControllerAttributes = string. Join(",", x.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))),
                Action = x.Name,
                ActionAttributes = string. Join(",", x.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", "")))
            })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Controller).ThenBy(x => x.Action).ToList();

//for detecting any action has Authorize attribute you can do this
if(controllerActionlist.Any(x=> x.Action=="YouAction" 
&& (x.ActionAttributes.Contains("Authorize") || x.ControllerAttributes.Contains("Authorize"))))
   //some stuff
```

Comment: Hello, in my case `FilterDescriptors` is empty so this won't work

Comment: @Oliver Answer updated

Comment: but again @Oliver wanted a solution where he won't use AuthorizeAttribute on controller  or action.

Comment: Exactly... I think the only way to solve this issue is to simulate what the ASP.NET Core authorization pipeline does. There should be a way to get the policy which the framework would use when testing against that action, I tried digging in the source code and experimenting a bit but i found none... /1

Comment: There two should be good starting point: [`AuthorizationMiddleware`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs#L62) and [`AuthorizeFilter`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Authorization/AuthorizeFilter.cs#L164) but unfortunately an `ActionDescriptor` is not enough, I think I would also need a mock `HttpContext` corresponding to a "fake" call against that action /2